# Can we use pytest to automate etl data validation. If yes then how do we create classes to validate a row of data

Tags: python, validation, automation, pytest, etl

I need to if this is really possible to write a pytest script to run over a set of say 1000 records.

Comment: I bet [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) is what you are looking for.

Comment: `pytest` is a framework for making sure your code behaves - i.e. that the validation routines that you have written gives the expected result for a given set of inputs. I'm not sure if this is what you're asking about, but having 1000 test cases is far from unusual for testing against many sets of possible inputs.